statsmodel glm and generalized linear model formula have inversed coefficient results
I am new to using statsmodel in python (and a lot of more generalized statistics in general), but I have a question regarding the difference between how sm.GLM and smf.glm calculate their results. From my understanding, as long as you ensure the added coefficient to sm.GLM, they should yield the same results. However, I found when I calculate it, the coefficients produced are the negative result of the other.
For example, using the sample datasets from the "Introduction to Statistical Learning for Python" book:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm

np.random.seed(0)
Default = pd.read_csv('../data/Default.csv')
X = Default[["balance", "income"]]
Y_=Default.default=='Yes'
X=sm.add_constant(X)
glmtest=sm.GLM(Y_,X,family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
glmtest.summary()


yields a balance coefficient of 0.0056. However, if I use smf
mod1 = smf.glm(
    formula="default~income+balance", data=Default, family=sm.families.Binomial()
).fit()
mod1.summary()

I instead get a coefficient of -0.0056. Other coefficients similarly have flipped signs. Since the results are the same ignoring the sign, I figure there was something going on under the hood and wanted to understand why.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2181#issuecomment-69671982

The work around is to make the dependent variable numeric when using the formula. Then the formula handling does not treat it as categorical.

Interesting. So when I tested it out, it does seem to flip around for smf. It appears from a quick glance at the github that smf is based on pasty python to convert to to numerical results, while the sm version uses the opposite numerics.

The difference arises because sm.GLM directly uses a boolean response variable (True as 1, False as 0), but smf.glm automatically encodes categorical variables based on their levels. THis can reverse the reference category. To make sure of obtaining the same results, explicitly check and align the response variable's encoding in both methods.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

np.random.seed(0)
data = {
    "default": np.random.choice(["Yes", "No"], size=100, p=[0.3, 0.7]),
    "balance": np.random.uniform(0, 2000, size=100),
    "income": np.random.uniform(20000, 100000, size=100)
}
Default = pd.DataFrame(data)

Y_ = Default.default == "Yes"  
X = Default[["balance", "income"]]
X = sm.add_constant(X)

glmtest = sm.GLM(Y_, X, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()

mod1 = smf.glm(formula="default ~ income + balance", data=Default, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()

print("sm.GLM coefficients:")
print(glmtest.params)

print("\nsmf.glm coefficients:")
print(mod1.params)


Which gives
sm.GLM coefficients:
const     -0.679362
balance   -0.000119
income     0.000002
dtype: float64

smf.glm coefficients:
Intercept    0.679362
income      -0.000002
balance      0.000119
dtype: float64

